# What exactly is lxcbr0?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware, remote-desktop

When I do ifconfig in terminal, I see lxcbr0 on. Upon googling I see that its like a Vmware. Is it this set-up by default because I did not set it up. Since its on, does this mean someone has remote access to my computer?

Answer (score 13):

On many Linux distributions, the LXC package will install startup scripts that pre-configure a bridge (basically, a software virtual switch) for use with LXC.

LXC is a set of tools for working with Linux's infrastructure for jails/zones/sandboxes. It builds on the same APIs used by Android to sandbox applications, for example. Some people use it for a lightweight linux-on-linux virtualization, but it is not the same thing as type 1 or type 2 hypervisors at all.

If you don't know what LXC is, it most likely got installed along with something else, such as virt-manager, which requires libvirt, which often requires LXC.

Comment: is it safe to disable it?

Comment: Yes. Some LXC and/or Docker functionality may become unavailable. If you don't know what those are, you won't miss it.

Comment: Virtualbox also uses it for the bridge network setting on a Virtual Machine.